# How to publish pose of the lidar/camera/(or any dynamic/static model) in gazebo fortress?

Tags: gazebo, rviz, pose, gazebo-plugin, sensor

I am trying publish the pose of the camera and view it in rviz2. I am using ros2 Humble and gazebo fortress. I can see the image using the image topic but i am not able to visualize the topic in the gazebo as well. Here is my sdf file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.6">
  <world name="test">
    <plugin
      filename="ignition-gazebo-physics-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Physics">
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="ignition-gazebo-sensors-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Sensors">
      <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="ignition-gazebo-user-commands-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::UserCommands">
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="ignition-gazebo-scene-broadcaster-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::SceneBroadcaster">
    </plugin>
    <light type="directional" name="sun">
      <cast_shadows>true</cast_shadows>
      <pose>0 0 10 0 0 0</pose>
      <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
      <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
      <attenuation>
        <range>1000</range>
        <constant>0.9</constant>
        <linear>0.01</linear>
        <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
      </attenuation>
      <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
    </light>

    <model name="ground_plane">
      <static>true</static>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0.0 0.0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0.0 0.0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <ambient>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</specular>
          </material>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>

    
    <model name="box">
      <pose>5.0 0 0.7 0 0 0</pose>
      <link name="box_link">
        <inertial>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>1</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>1</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>1</izz>
          </inertia>
          <mass>1.0</mass>
        </inertial>
        <collision name="box_collision">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>1 1 1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </collision>

        <visual name="box_visual">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>1 1 1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.3 0.5 0.3 1</specular>
          </material>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>

    <model name="model_with_camera">
      <static>true</static>
      <pose>4 -6 2 0 0 1.57</pose>
      <link name="link">
        <pose>0.05 0.05 0.05 0 0 0</pose>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
        <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
          <camera>
            <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
              <width>640</width>
              <height>480</height>
            </image>
            <clip>
              <near>0.1</near>
              <far>100</far>
            </clip>
          </camera>
          <always_on>1</always_on>
          <update_rate>30</update_rate>
          <visualize>true</visualize>
          <topic>camera</topic>
        </sensor>
      </link>
    </model>

    
    <model name="lidar">
      <pose>4.05 -6 2 0 0 1.57</pose>
      <link name="link">
        <pose>0.05 0.05 0.05 0 0 0</pose>
        <inertial>
          <mass>0.1</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>0.000166667</ixx>
            <iyy>0.000166667</iyy>
            <izz>0.000166667</izz>
          </inertia>
        </inertial>
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </visual>

        <sensor name='gpu_lidar' type='gpu_lidar'>
          <topic>lidar</topic>
          <update_rate>10</update_rate>
          <lidar>
            <scan>
              <horizontal>
                <samples>1024</samples>
                <resolution>1</resolution>
                <min_angle>-1.396263</min_angle>
                <max_angle>1.396263</max_angle>
              </horizontal>
              <vertical>
                <samples>64</samples>
                <resolution>1</resolution>
                <min_angle>-0.261799</min_angle>
                <max_angle>0.261799</max_angle>
              </vertical>
            </scan>
            <range>
              <min>0.08</min>
              <max>30.0</max>
              <resolution>0.01</resolution>
            </range>
          </lidar>
          <alwaysOn>1</alwaysOn>
          <visualize>true</visualize>
        </sensor>

        <plugin
            filename="ignition-gazebo-pose-publisher-system"
            name="gz::sim::systems::PosePublisher">
            <publish_link_pose>true</publish_link_pose>
            <publish_sensor_pose>true</publish_sensor_pose>
            <use_pose_vector_msg>true</use_pose_vector_msg>
            <static_publisher>true</static_publisher>
        </plugin>
      </link>
      <static>true</static>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

I tried to publish the pose of the lidar using pose-publisher-system as well.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Gazebo Sim system plugin can only be attached to a `<world>`, a `<model>` or a `<sensor>`, not to a `<link>`. You should be getting an error message for this in the log output, I think even without verbose output enabled. In any case: for testing purposes it is advisable to enable verbose output (`-v 4`), e.g.:

```
ign gazebo -v 4 world.sdf
```

All standard Gazebo Fortress system plugins can be found in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/ign-gazebo6/src/systems). See the other branches of that repository for the other Gazebo Sim versions.

Each plugin has usage documentation in its header file. For the `PosePublisher` system see [this part of the header file](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/14b0f3b42da811cdd8fb24e983c2b2598a855c91/src/systems/pose_publisher/PosePublisher.hh#L35-L66).

I haven't used that plugin yet, but given following documentation I conclude that you just have to add the plugin to the `<model>` in order to get all pose information published:

> Attach to an entity to publish the transform of its child entities in the form of gz::msgs::Pose messages, or a single gz::msgs::Pose_V message if "use_pose_vector_msg" is true.

The GitHub repository also holds [example worlds](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/ign-gazebo6/examples/worlds) that show the use of each plugin. [Here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/ign-gazebo6/examples/worlds/pose_publisher.sdf) is the one for the pose publisher.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply.